# I can't save roles to my devise user table (for cancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, roles

I have installed Devise and CanCan, both which appear to be working. I have the column "role" in migrations but when I check the log after adding a user, the BD query shows no sign of adding a role

The full thing looks like this:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S+SjhxsALMbHkRBPPwOMIvHo1Bd0cNYl1g=", "user"=>{"email"=>"david@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "role"=>"receptionist"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: role
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'david@mail.com' LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `encrypted_password`
  SQL (3.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 08:52:31 UTC +00:00], ["email", "david@mail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$e3hKTibsZ7qSgOC5OelKgjumU8ufu46xNrBkmXcDEpix/m"], ["updated_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 08:52:31 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `last_sign_in_ip`
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `current_sign_in_ip`
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_ip" = ?, "current_sign_in_ip" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 2  [["last_sign_in_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 08:52:31 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 08:52:31 UTC +00:00], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", Thu, 24 Oct 2013 08:52:31 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 108ms (ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
```

Additionally, if I **edit user** and add the role I get the following error in the logs

> Unpermitted parameters: role

I feel like the migrations may not have worked.. but I can access the role variable.. so I don't fully understand.

I'm fairly new to rails, so I'm expecting (and hoping) I've omitted something obvious.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are u using rails 3 or rails 4?

Comment: Hi, I'm using rails 3

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it that error `Unpermitted parameters:role` means you haven't whitelisted this in your application. I am aware that your there is a change in your application in handling the attribute protection. So you need to `whitelist` this parameter. If this was rails 4 you would do something like this:

```
class User < ActionController::Base
  def create
    User.create(params[:user])
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, :role)
  end
end
```

The above is a change that comes with Rails 4. However in your case (rails 3) I think you just need to make this attribute accessible. So you could try and add the following to your User model.

```
attr_accessible :role
```

Answer (score 0):

in your aplication controller

```
      before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
 protected
 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation,:current_password,:email,:name,:role) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation,:email,:name,:role) }
 end
```

it worked for me!